# Migrating from Numergy to Bluemix

Tags: migration, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have some servers on the cloud Numergy and I want to migrate to Bluemix.

Can I migrate my servers directly, or I can migrate only my apps from Numergy to Bluemix?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct migration path between Numergy and Bluemix. You would need to upload your application to Bluemix and link to any dependent services. Thanks for your interest in Bluemix!